# Which Fortran 77 format specifiers will never be used for input?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Still working on making a fortran I/O for C#. My limited fortran experience doesn't help really, so I once again need some advice from experts.

I'm just concerned with Fortran 77 and data input at the moment. I will get around to data output later.

[From this list](http://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/a2.html#section8) of fortran edit descriptors, I have coded up I, F, E, D, G, L, A, '', Tn, TL, TR, and X so far for data input. Still need to take care of BN and BZ...

I am wondering if the rest of the symbols $, :, /, Sp, SS and S actually ever occur in format string for data input? I can imagine that / might if reading the data line is to be terminated early, but I don't see how the other could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` isn't a valid Fortran 77 descriptor.  It is used in extensions.

`:` terminates format processing in the absence of further list items.  It may make a difference in some corner cases where there are invalid format specifications for input following, but perhaps that's invalid regardless.

`/` is certainly significant.

"The `SP`, `SS` and `S` edit descriptors have no effect during the execution of an input statement."  (F77 13.5.6 p3)

(The apostrophe descriptor (character literal) isn't valid in a format specification for input anyway.  I don't see `P` in your list.  When it comes time for output and Fortran 77, don't forget `H`...)

Comment: Note that "have no effect" doesn't mean "will never be used".  In some cases the same format descriptor was used for input and output of the same data.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, so I am parsing for them and just skipping them for data input. By the way, when you say that apostrophe is not valid, would a fortran program throw an error if it found `'SomeString'` in an format statement for input, or would it just ignore it? I assumed initially it would assign it to a CHARACTER variable provided that one was provided...

Comment: The program is invalid.  The Fortran processor can do whatever it wants to do.  Ignoring it, reporting an error, exploding mysteriously at some later point in the program, launching a nuclear strike or sleeping with the programmer's spouse are all valid responses.

Comment: Lol! OK, I get it, so I can do whatever I want then, that's cool. Thanks again for your help.